# What is this gray-green plant with magenta flowers?

Tags: identification

The plant below has flowers about 1+1/4 inch (32mm) across.  The leaves are soft and maybe slightly fuzzy; they feel like thin suede.  This is growing in the Williamette valley in Oregon mainly on a sunny, grassy slope.  I don't know if is a native or a naturalized garden plant (the latter seems more likely, but don't know if it is widespread or local to one property).  Seems moderately successful competing in those sunny grassy areas.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is [*Silene coronaria*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silene_coronaria), commonly known as Rose Campion. Identifying characteristics are the almost fluorescent magenta flowers and the gray-green leaves. In winter, the plants die back to a rosette of leaves at the base of the plant, or disappear completely, depending on how harsh the winter is. They put out leaves in early spring and have a short flowering season in late spring to early summer.

It's native to Europe, so you're seeing it naturalized. It's not listed as invasive by the [State of Oregon](http://plants.usda.gov/java/noxious?rptType=State&statefips=41), but is considered to be by the [Native Plant Society of Oregon](http://emerald.npsoregon.org/index.htm). I have some in my yard, and it definitely spreads, but is also easily controlled by pulling the seedlings when it pops up in new places.